# How to address the TableAdapter of a Dataset (made by wizard)

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, dataset

I created a new datasource with 4 tables of a sql database. In my first form i created a to_table_1 _bounded gridview via drag and drop. This created table Adapter and table adapter manager for example, which a bound to the form. Now I have a module1 where I want to perform an Insert Statement from the Table2Tableadapter. But I dont know how i can talk to the adapter, if I not create a gridview anywhere. I want to talk to the Datset.xsd table2 Adapter. Ther I already set up the sql Statements and the Insert statement is nevertheless Standard implemented in the adapter.

I know this must be so easy for someone who worked more then one time with databases. Hope You can help!

Cheers Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do your data access in a module then don't create the table adapter in the form; create it in the module.  The Data Source wizard generates classes and you use those classes the same way you would any other.  Do you have a problem using a `String` in a module?  Of course not.,  If you want a `String` then you create a `String`.  The same goes for a table adapter.

When you drag items onto a form from the Data Sources window it will generate some items automatically.  There's no requirement that you keep all those items.  Just delete the table adapter and manager and any code that uses them, then write your own code to populate a `DataTable` in your module.  You've still got the `DataSet` in the form so you simply pass that, or a specific `DataTable` it contains, to your module to populate it.

You could go further and remove the `DataSet` from the form too and then use the `GetData` method of your table adapter to create a new `DataTable` and return that to the form.  It's up to you.  Don't limit yourself by what's generated for you.  That is there to help but it's not the only way to do things.  If you want to create something then create it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It wasnt to much and it wasnt to less. It brought me on my way. 

For an Example on how to create a Table Adapter use this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx